# How to replace list of special characters to a single char in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
data = ["Beer&", "&Whiskey", "Wine()","Tonic$", "Rum*"]

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Col'] = data
```

```
     Col
0   Beer&
1   &Whiskey
2   Wine()
3   Tonic$
4   Rum*
```

I want to replace the list of special characters with a single character

```
spl_char = "$&+:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-"
char_list = list(spl_char)

df["Col"] = df["Col"].replace(dict.fromkeys(char_list,  ','))
```

Using the above syntax I don't see any changes.

And when I tried with `str`, I'm getting the below error

```
df["Col"] = df["Col"].str.replace(dict.fromkeys(char_list,  ','))
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-53b53a25fc97> in <module>()
----> 1 df["Col"] = df["Col"].str.replace(dict.fromkeys(char_list,  ','))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/strings.py in wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1999                 )
   2000                 raise TypeError(msg)
-> 2001             return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2002 
   2003         wrapper.__name__ = func_name

TypeError: replace() missing 1 required positional argument: 'repl'
```

How can I replace all the special characters with a single character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace everything excluding alphanumerics with nothing. Code below.

```
df['Col']= df['Col'].str.replace('[^\w]', '')

      Col
0     Beer
1  Whiskey
2     Wine
3    Tonic
4      Rum
```

Comment: Nice, i  didn't thought of it. if the OP wants only alphanumerics then this is definitely the best way to go ;)

Comment: Instead of `[^\w]`, can simply use `\W`